# SQL Query for finding a unique Item in one of many tables

Tags: sql, search

I have the need to search for an item that exists in one of many (~20) tables
I can safely assume that the item only exists in one of the tables, all tables contains an index with the same column name and value type.

Tables vary in on of their columns, containing one of a few possible value types (int, string, binary. etc.)

What would be the most efficient way to search for the item, of a few items that match a criteria?
Please note that there is NO NEED for any join, as item is uniquely stored in **one** row in **one** table.

Comment: Do you need to know which table it was found in, or simply whether or not it exists?

Comment: "item is uniquely stored in one row in one table" -- to know this you must already have a multi-table constraint. The definition of this constraint will give you a huge clue in how to write your query.

Comment: @winston There is no need to know what is the originating Table (i can also probably deduct it from the resulting content)

Comment: @onedaywhen i'm not sure i understand what you mean, but i can say that when i'm looking for the item there is no way to tell on which table it will be.

Comment: Let me turn the question around: how can you "safely assume" the item doesn't appear in two (or more) tables? What is providing the "safety" here?

Comment: For example, in one of my databases I know that every entity appears in zero or one of a number of tables because each of those tables has a foreign key back to the entity table, referencing it by a compound key of entity ID and entity type, and each table has a distinct `CHECK` constraint on entity type. Looking at the information schema views would tell you all this.

Comment: @onedaywhen: Safety is maintained by the managing service, storage is directed for each item to one specific table. you can safely use this uniqueness as a working assumption.

Comment: @Amit Ben Shahar: so your 'managing service' is the trusted source of data constraints rather than the database itself. I now see the source of the problem. The solution then would seem to be, if the 'managing service' knows the entity type at the time of insertion then it should record this information somewhere so that it can be retrieved later... in the database perhaps? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL UNION with the 20+ tables enumerated in the UNION.  You could set this up as a view then use the view for selection.

For the single column that varies you could convert all the types to a string for the view.

For an example:

```
CREATE VIEW Combined_Table AS
SELECT keyfield, Cast(Integerb as varchar) as varcharfield
  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT keyfield, varcharfield
  FROM table2
UNION ...
```

then you can use the view as a table:

```
SELECT keyfield, varcharfield
  FROM Combined_table
 WHERE keyfield = 'key'
```

Comment: (probably a newbie question) Can you maybe explain/demonstrate using a view? (first time crossing this term). 10x

Comment: Another concern is performance, so i would like to stop the search once a result is found (as i know there is only 1), so would applying a ROWCOUNT (max results) make sure that the query stops after one result?

Comment: Or better phrased: Another concern is performance, so i would like to stop the search once a result is found (as i know there is only 1), so how do i apply a limit in a way that ensures the query stops after one result?

Comment: If, as you say, there is only one row for each key then you don't need to do any limits.  Just make sure you have an index of the key on each table.  Then when you select on the view it would just have to check each table's index once.

Comment: The point was avoiding checking additional indexes when for instance the result is found in the first table, then checking the others is redundant..